# Setting coordinator names in Oozie bundle from bundle.properties

Tags: bundle, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I'm using an Oozie bundle to manage two coordinators (for now).  They are the same process, but for two different clients.  I have the client names defined in the `bundle.properties` file that I call when I launch the `bundle.xml`.  I'm trying to use the client name to name each of the coordinators, but I keep seeing variations of the following error:

> Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-pattern-valid: Value
>   'Daily_job_#{client1}' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern
>   '(a-zA-Z*){1,39}' for type 'IDENTIFIER'

I have been playing around with using ${} to access the variable name vs #{} based on this post here: [Renaming Oozie coordinator dynamically.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564493/can-i-rename-the-oozie-job-name-dynamically) I seem to be able to access the variables as properties just fine from the `bundle.properties` just not in the name.

Here is what I've tried in the `bundle.xml`:

```
<coordinator name='Daily_job_#{client1}' >
...
      <property>
          <name>client</name>
          <value>${client1}</value>
      </property>

</coordinator>
```

and

```
<coordinator name='Daily_job_${client1}' >
...
</coordinator>
```

In the `bundle.properties`:

```
client1=firstclientname
client2=secondclientname
```

I'm able to access the value of client within the property in the coordinator and workflow but I can't seem to name the coordinator based on the property.  Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're getting that particular error seems to indicate the name which happens to be a bundle:IDENTIFIER type does not conform to the schema that was defined by the Oozie developers.

What this means is that your XML is being validated for well-formedness against a schema and the bundle:IDENTIFIER is checked against a regular expression that only allows alphanumerics, dashes and underscores in the name with a minimum of 1 character up to 40 characters.

```
<xs:simpleType name="IDENTIFIER">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z]([\-_a-zA-Z0-9])*){1,39})"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Well-formedness is a XML pre-processing step and is probably restricting your substitution characters as $ # { } are not included in the regular expression.

https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/master/client/src/main/resources/oozie-bundle-0.2.xsd

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It seems like that means that it can't read a variable?  I was hoping there was some way to pass variables that I hadn't identified yet but maybe that isn't the case. I was able to use the ${} format to label coordinators in the coordinator.xml so I thought that might translate to the bundle as well.

Comment: The link is to the schema for the latest Oozie Bundle XML.  I included it because it shows what it validates against.  If you notice, in the newer version, the schema has been updated to accept any string as opposed to the bundle:IDENTIFIER simple type.  This will get you past the well-formedness validation.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Oozie bundle schema 0.1: `xmlns='uri:oozie:bundle:0.1'`, and by changing it to 0.2:`xmlns='uri:oozie:bundle:0.2'` it works now.  I am also using the second variation with ${}, so in the `bundle.xml`:

```
<coordinator name='Daily_job_${client1}' >
...
</coordinator>
```

Is the one to use.